# php configuration is different with symlink

Tags: ubuntu, php.ini, php-cli

php configuration doesn't have the same timezone when i use symlink!

```
xxxx:/usr/bin $ php -i | grep timezone                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Default timezone => Europe/Berlin
date.timezone => no value => no value

xxxx:/usr/bin $ php7.2 -i | grep timezone                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Default timezone => Europe/Paris
date.timezone => Europe/Paris => Europe/Paris

xxxx:/usr/bin $ ll php*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      21 Aug 31  2017 php -> /etc/alternatives/php*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 9114792 Aug  4  2017 php5*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4764912 Mar  6 13:50 php7.2*

xxxx:/usr/bin $ ll /etc/alternatives/php*                                                                                                                                                                                                      
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Mar  8 17:25 /etc/alternatives/php -> /usr/bin/php7.2*
```

Comment: I don't think the symlink points where you think it does - it looks like it refers to /etc/alternatives/php7.2, not /use/bin/php7.2. Also, when running tests, rub as .,/php as this forces it to run from current dir, not path.

Comment: $ which php > return: /usr/bin/php -> /etc/alternatives/php -> /usr/bin/php7.2